# Finding MAD, MAPE, and MSE in R for Holt-Winters and ARIMA forecast

Tags: r, forecasting, arima, holtwinters

Im looking for the best way to calculate the MAD, MAPE, MSE in R for a Holt-Winters and ARIMA forecast model. Below is my code for my models and any guidance would be awesome

Holt-Winters Model and Prediction:

```
#Holt-Winters Exponential Smoothing
forecast.mean <- HoltWinters(Abbeville$Incoming.Examinations,gamma=FALSE)


#Predicting ahead the next 12 months
forecast.predict <- predict(forecast.mean, n.ahead = 12, prediction.interval = TRUE)
```

ARIMA model and Forecast

```
ARIMA_forecast <- auto.arima(x=Abbeville$Incoming.Examinations)

ARIMA_nextforecasting <- forecast(ARIMA_forecast, h=12)
```

Comment: Use the `accuracy` function from the forecast package.

Comment: Thank you, It worked for my ARIMA model, but not my Holts-Winter model. I receive this error: Error in accuracy.default(forecast.predict) : 
  First argument should be a forecast object or a time series. This is what forecast.predict looks like: forecast.predict <- predict(forecast.mean, n.ahead = 12, prediction.interval = TRUE)

Comment: Use the forecast function to make predictions, not predict.

Comment: Perfect, thank you that worked.